# Showing different content in Angular without having new components?

Tags: javascript, html, angular

Let's assume I have a component `mycomponent` with 5 different hyperlinks.
Below them I have a `div` whose content I'd like to change in accordance to the link that was clicked last.

So my structure is:

```
Link 1 -> Show "Link1 clicked"
Link 2 -> Show "Link2 clicked"
Link 3 -> Show "Link3 clicked"
Link 4 -> Show "Link4 clicked"
Link 5 -> Show "Link5 clicked"
```

My approach would be to create a variable `this.page = 0`
and displaying the content on the HTML via

```
<ng-template [ngIf]="this.page == 1">Link 1 clicked</ng-template>
<ng-template [ngIf]="this.page == 2">Link 2 clicked</ng-template>
<ng-template [ngIf]="this.page == 3">Link 3 clicked</ng-template>
<ng-template [ngIf]="this.page == 4">Link 4 clicked</ng-template>
<ng-template [ngIf]="this.page == 5">Link 5 clicked</ng-template>
```

Is this a good way to do it?
How would it be better?

What approach should I choose to automatically choose the right `ng-template` according to a URL paramter?
E.g. `mydomain.com/link1` should result in showing `mycomponent` displaying `Link 1`

Please have a look at the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qluk8e) I created for better understanding. It does not include approaches concerning the routing mentioned above as I do not have any approach idea I could share.

Comment: since many things and assumptions are involved in your question, please create stackblitz for that

Comment: Thanks! I just added a stackblitz, please feel free to have a look at it.

Comment: I just checked the stackblitz no routing is involved, but in your question you mentioned `mydomain.com/link1`, because considering routing or not considering will affect the solution

Comment: Right, I do not how I would approach this as mentioned in the post.
Obviously it wouldn't be a problem just to route to e.g. `mydomain.com/link1` but I do not know how it would be possible to change the `page` variable by routing differently.

Comment: because if you want to do it by routing, you need to define routes and the having a router outlet and angular do everything for you